# Problem in write ascii string builder to a file

Tags: c#, file, ascii

I try to write a string include some character to a file like that:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("3S@Þ>‡g3¶UH3úUH3?UH3UH3âUH3ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿUH3ÇUH3ÿÿÿÿUH3EêL3");
File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, sb.ToString());
```

but in the end, I have a file include this:

> 3S@Ãž>Â‡g3Â¶UH3ÃºUH3?UH3UH3Ã¢U

I just know my file must be like that:

[image]

How can I write this string to a file .bin?

Comment: You are trying to write bytes, not characters. Use `File.WriteAllBytes(new byte[] { 0x33, 0x53, 0x40, 0xde, ...})` instead (or build up a `List<byte>` if you have more than one such sequence).

Comment: Define what a .bin file is and what its content should be. .bin is just a fileextension used for many things.

Comment: You're trying to write a file with obvious binary content (as in, not interpretable as text) using text methods. Don't do that. Write the raw bytes you expect the file to have instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jeroen Mostert.

I use `File.WriteAllBytes(new byte[] { 0x33, 0x53, 0x40, 0xde, ...})` and work correctly.